# Why am I getting ResultSet is closed error when I never closed any

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, resultset, sqlexception

I have this error in my code and have checked and edited it thoroughly, yet I still get same issue. I also use multiple resultSet and Statements yet same error occurs. Below is the error I get:

```
    "Database Connected with Current Date 20130221
    java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is closed
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.checkOpen(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.next(Unknown Source)
    at UNSUB.main(UNSUB.java:78)"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Please What could be the reason? I have no idea on any solution now.

Comment: post your code here only then we can help.

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: Note that the resultset gets closed when the statement or connection gets closed. The result set depends on the statement, which depends on the connection.

Comment: Can you please share some sort of code

Comment: ok. I'll be sending it soonest

Comment: My code is too large to be posted... pls how can I get over that?

Comment: post only the snippet, where you're extracting data from the `resultSet`. Nobody is interested in the rest of the code anyways.

Answer (score 5):

The exception, `java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is closed` means that your code has either already closed the result set object
you're using, or more likely, that your code has either re-executed or closed the statement that
produced the result set. By JDBC specs, either of those actions will close any
result set from the statement.

Comment: thanks for your reply. In the code I have a nested resultSet with a different statement yet error occurs.

Comment: share the code, which will help in pointing out the exact erroneous block.

Comment: `rs1 = stmt2.executeQuery("select cnt from t1 where num = '"+ str2 +"'"); rs1.next(); cnt = rs1.getInt("cnt"); if(cnt > 0) { rs2 = stmt3.executeQuery("select * from t1 where num = '123"); while (rs2.next()) { reg_date = rs2.getString("reg"); ins1 = stmt3.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO t2 ([num]) VALUES('"+ str2 +"')"); Thread.sleep(10); ins2 = stmt3.executeUpdate("delete from t1 where num = '"+ str2 +"'); } }`

Answer (score -2):

Have you called the method `next()` on the ResultSet?? If you haven't that might be the reason for you to get that error.

Comment: Yes I called the .next() method and changed the statement name. I would be willing to share code if needed. thanks

Comment: The stacktrace in the question clearly shows that `next()` has been called

Comment: didn't notice the next() method being called.

Comment: You seem to keep forgetting to close single quotes. While executing stmt3, u have missed `'` at the end and while executing the delete statement, u have missed a double quotes. Check those and let me know if it works.

Comment: Oh! sorry about that. It is a typo error when editing in the message box. That is not the problem I am having. My code compiles and runs but later throws an exception(while running). Thanks

Comment: It still gives me same error. pls what other issue can cause this error? I am stocked